# Problem decoding a JSON resopnse from an API service

Tags: php, json, php-7, guzzle, guzzle6

i have a problem dedoding a JSON response from a webservice using Guzzle 6 under Laravel 6.

The response i'm trying to decode is here:

https://json.volotea.com/dist/stations/stations.json

In my php code i try in this way:

```
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->request('GET','https://json.volotea.com/dist/stations/stations.json');
```

To decode the response i tried several methods like:

```
$response->getBody();  // that returns a stream

$response->getBody()->getContents(); that returns an apparently correct answer but if I run the json_decode it returns a null as a result
```

I'm going crazy!

How can i decode the response from this service?

many thanks

Comment: jsonlint.com says its valid but PHP `json_decode()` gives the error `- Syntax error, malformed JSON` It is a HUGE result so finding the issue may be slow. Or maybe the issue is that the json is so big

Comment: Just tried using `file_get_contents("https://json.volotea.com/dist/stations/stations.json")` which the `json_decode()` fails, downloaded the file and used it from local drive and it's OK.  The problem seems to be that the json is all on one line which crashes it.

Comment: Copied the JsonString to a variable and the `json_decode()` works find! Put the JSON all in one line and it still worked. I am thinking its to do with the size of the response for some reason

Comment: I have managed to read it, was a case of save it to a file and use JsonStreamingParser to read it (a JSON streaming parser).  If you get stuck I can put an answer up how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems with method getContent you already manipulated Json structure 
try json_decode on $response.